# Scala function body definition help wanted

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I'm trying making a scala dsl with this syntax:

```scala
val a = Agent() setup { agent => // agent reference.
  agent add "Hello World!"
}
a add "Not allowed" // Atm this is allowed.
```

where I can call method add outside the setup function body and to call add method I have to write `agent =>` at the beginning of setup function body.

What I've done atm is a trait Agent:

```scala
trait Agent {

  def setup(f: Agent => Unit): Agent

  def add(s: String): Agent
}

case class AgentImpl(strings: Seq[String]) extends Agent {
  override def setup(f: Agent => Unit): Agent = {
    f(this)
    this
  }

  override def add(s: String): Agent = copy(strings = strings:+s)
}

object Agent {
  def apply(): Agent = AgentImpl(Seq.empty)
}
```

What I have to do is this:

```scala
val a = Agent() setup { // No more references to agent
    add "Hello World!"
  }
  a add "Not allowed" // This mustn't be allowed. Compilation error.
```

where I haven't a reference to agent with `agent =>` at the start of setup function body and if I try to do an add outside the setup function body I get an error.

Is this possible in Scala?

I can change every part of the code, add any number of traits/classes/objects and other things but not change the syntax of my DSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```scala
sealed trait Agent {
  def getFoos: List[String]
  def getBars: List[Int]
}

object Agent {
  import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
  
  private final class Builder {
    private[this] val foos: ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer.empty
    private[this] val bars: ListBuffer[Int] = ListBuffer.empty
    
    private def addFoo(foo: String): Unit = {
      foos += foo
    }
    
    private def addBar(bar: Int): Unit = {
      bars += bar
    }
    
    private[Agent] def result(): Agent = new Agent {
      override final val getFoos: List[String] =
        foos.result()
      
      override final val getBars: List[Int] =
        bars.result()
    }
  }
  
  private[Agent] type BuilderStep = Builder => Unit
  
  object Builder {
    private[Agent] def create() = new Builder()
    
    object Steps {
      def addFoo(foo: String): BuilderStep =
        _.addFoo(foo)
      
      def addBar(bar: Int): BuilderStep =
        _.addBar(bar)
    }
  }
  
  def setup(steps: BuilderStep*): Agent = {
    val builder = Builder.create()
    steps.foreach(s => s(builder))
    builder.result()
  }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```scala
import Agent.Builder.Steps._

val agent = Agent.setup(
  addFoo("A"),
  addFoo("B"),
  addBar(1),
  addBar(2),
  addFoo("C"),
  addBar(3),
  addFoo("D")
)
```

But maybe a traditional immutable builder would be equally good and simpler.

---

*Code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/kmjKAZXqSA2MOs43f8fYpA/4)*.

Comment: Hi @Luis, thank you. This will help me a lot. There's a trick to avoid to repeat commas between add calls or is impossible to avoid them?

Comment: Sorry @Luis for another request: with your solution, I'm still able to call addBar and addFoo outside the setup function, and generally instance BuilderStep outside the setup function. There are any possibility to deny that?

Comment: Yes, you can call them but they are doing nothing. And not, is impossible to make something only available in a single function block without using extreme features like macros.